# How to use SemanticallyAdvisedMethodKinds instead of ApplyToStateMachine?

Tags: c#, postsharp

I was using ApplyToStateMachine in my code and this was set to false in the constructor of my class.
Now with latest version of PostSharp, I am seeing that this is obsolete and I need to use SemanticallyAdvisedMethodKinds.
How can I replace SemanticallyAdvisedMethodKinds with ApplyToStateMachine to have same behavior as I was having earlier when ApplyToStateMachine was set to false?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the same behavior as with the `ApplyToStateMachine` property set to `false`, set the `SemanticallyAdvisedMethodKinds` property to `SemanticallyAdvisedMethodKinds.None`.

For more on this topic, see http://doc.postsharp.net/semantic-advising.